# Input element focus, hover and padding not behaving in all browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form that I'm styling at the moment. I simply want the outline of the form to change to red when active and nothing to happen when hovered over.

I have this working in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer. I'm using Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7.

In IE, at the moment there is a default hover which I can't figure out and when clicking in the input element, the outline-color doesn't change.

Another issue is that I have applied padding-left inside the input so that both the placeholder and user's text aren't touching the edge. For some reason, this has pushed the entire input to be wider than it should. It does have `max-width: 100%` applied to it. The div that contains the form has padding on the sides and now the input is pushing into the padding. This occurs in all browsers.

Here is basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/fr7Lz2wj/1/

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="contactForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required maxlength="65" tabindex="1">
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#contactForm{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 64em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.25em;   
} 

input {
     width: 100%;
     height: 3em;
     padding-left: 1em;
     &:focus {
         outline-color: red;
     }
     &:hover {
         outline-color: none;
     }
 }
```

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the input field to go over either you apply a percentage padding (ie. 1.5% ) and set input width at 100% minus 1.5% (98.5%) or you have to use css box-sizing:border-box on the input itself.
To have outline on focus you have to specify an outline-style.

```
input {
 width: 100%;
 height: 3em;
 padding-left: 1em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    &:focus {
        outline-style: dotted;
        outline-color: red; 
    }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fr7Lz2wj/5/